# Graph Colouring in using adjacency matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, backtracking

I am trying to solve the coloring problem with backtracking. I am unable to get proper output, but my logic is correct. I should get `1 2 3 2`, but I am getting `1 2 2 2`. What is going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define V 4


bool isitsafetocolourVwiththisC(bool graph[V][V], int v, int c, int color[V])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    {
        if(graph[v][i] && (c == color[i]))
            return false;
        return true;        
    }
}


bool graphColoring(bool graph[V][V], int m, int v, int color[V])
{
    if (v == V)
        return true;

    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        if (isitsafetocolourVwiththisC(graph, v, i, color))
        {
            color[v] = i;
            if (graphColoring(graph, m, v+1, color))
                return true;
            color[v] = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


void printcolours(int color[V])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        cout << color[i] << " ";
}


int main()
{

    bool graph[V][V] = {{0, 1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0},
                        {1, 1, 0, 1},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0}};
    int m = 3; // Number of colors
    int color[V];
    memset(color, 0, sizeof color);
    bool flag = graphColoring(graph, m, 0, color);
    if (flag)
        printcolours(color);
    else 
        cout << "Solution doesn't exist.";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `isitsafetocolourVwiththisC`, shouldn't `return true` be outside the for-loop? This could be seen more easily with a better indentation strategy. `clang` emits a warning about it, too.

Comment: Nope i think iits correct to have false over there . If no such solution is possible after all backtracking , then it should return false.

Comment: Consider using references to const when passing parameters. Your `int color[V]` (macros are evil, btw) is just a `int* color` in disguise. Use `typedef int colormap[V]` to define a type that you can then conveniently reference as `colormap const& color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your logic is correct, your output will be correct. ;)

I ran this myself to confirm, after I moved `return true` out of the for-loop. It works correctly now.

```
bool isitsafetocolourVwiththisC(bool graph[V][V], int v, int c, int color[V])
{
    for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
    {
        if(graph[v][i] &&  (c == color[i]))
            return false;
        // Not returning here anymore!
    }
    return true;
}
```

The reason is that in the other place, you never process any other elements of the list. You must return true or false after the first element.

I don't know which compiler you're using, but `clang` complains with your original code—let the compiler help you.

```
myfile.cpp:15:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function
      [-Wreturn-type]
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much :) I though you were talking about false in graphcolouring method . Thank you so much :)